# Node JS API responds nothing on increasing request params and keeps sending the request to the server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using following api which responds nothing
http://localhost:6150/api/v1/simpleSurveyData/abc/:projectId/:startDate/:endDate/:visitMonth

but, when i remove any of the four params or give less than four params. And adjust api route in node js accordingly server starts to response.

What i found is increasing params to four, my Node JS code does not come into the api route but although server does not give error but request just sending.

```
router.get("api/v1/simpleSurveyData/abc/:projectId/:startDate/:endDate/:visitMonth",
  async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("first")

    try {
      console.log("first")
 
      res.status(200).send("response");
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you using express js or something ? Also please show the code

Comment: i am using express

Comment: How and from where are you calling the GET request?

Comment: i called using both postman and browser too. i am curious why my code starts working and all console log gets started work when i remove any of the four req params

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you extract the data from url path NOT a query parameter. Please use query parameter. Example code below.

`"api/v1/simpleSurveyData/abc/:projectId/:startDate/:endDate/:visitMonth"` should be `"api/v1/simpleSurveyData/abc?projectId=<projectId>&startDate=<startDate>&endDate=<endDate>&visitMonth=<visitMonth>"`

Example express controller

```
export async function upvoteQuestion(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const questionId: string = req.params.question_id
        await db<Question>('question').where('id', questionId).increment('upvote', 1)
        res.status(200).json(<GeneralResponse>{
            status: responseStatus.success,
            message: 'Successfully vote up question'
        })
    } catch (error: unknown) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```

I extract the information of question id in url parameter by using `req.params.question_id`.

You can Google for more information.